# How to keep python interpreter in memory across executions?

Tags: python

I need to repeatedly call short programs in python.

Since programs are trivial, but use several (standard) modules and target hardware (embedded ARM9 running linux) is not very powerful loading time of interpreter+libs greatly exceeds prog runtime.

Is there a way to keep a python interpreter in memory and "just" feed it a program to execute?

I know I can write a fairly simple "C" wrapper spawning the interpreter and then feed it my programs via PyRun_SimpleFile(), but that looks like an overkill. Surely there's some simpler (and probably more "pythonic") way of achieving the same.

Comment: you could start a process with a pipe with `python -` and feed it input through the process stdin. Get results through stdout.

Comment: However without knowing what does scripts do you may end up with inconsistent state and unpredictable behaviour. I advice modifying those scripts to endlessly accept input (if possible).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: would that be similar to use python from the command line? I mean: I could load all my "programs" as separate routines and then "just" call them with the right arguments with a single line sent to pipe?

Comment: @ZioByte yes, exact same thing.

Comment: Nothing better than CGI/FCGI was invented (and became popular enough) so far for this task, as I can say (which are exactly the subject your looking for, as I understand). No one has bothered to implement something better worth to mention since

Comment: @freakish: Your solution would keep multiple interpreters in memory all the time, I guess. If that's so then the memory overhead may be too high for my hardware (256Mb RAM). Scripts are really "just" wrappers around urllib doing a series of canned remote requests and returning the (compound) result. Currently I have a set of shell scripts around curl, but it's becoming too complex for comfort, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: @agg3l: actually I have the reverse problem: I need to send "canned" sequence of requests, triggered by user from user interaction. AFAIK FCGI is done to process incoming requests using a programmatic backend. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways of solving this problem.

A simple one would be to combine all your short programs into a simple web application, potentially one that listens on a local Unix socket rather than a network socket.  E.g., using the minimal Flask application in the [flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!\n'
```

You could expose it on a local Unix socket like this, assuming you've put the above code into a script called `myapp.py`:

```
uwsgi --http-socket /tmp/app.sock --manage-script-name --plugin python --mount /=myapp:app
```

And now you can access it like this (note the single `/` in `http:/`; that's because we don't need a hostname when connecting to a local socket):

```
$ curl --unix-socket /tmp/app.sock http:/
Hello, world!
```

This would let you start your Python scripts once and let it run persistently, thus avoiding the costs associated with start up and module loading for subsequent calls, while providing you with a way to run different functions, provide input parameters, etc.

Here's an example that takes a filename as input and performs some transformations on the file:

```
@app.route('/cmd1', methods=['POST'])
def cmd1():
    inputfile = request.form.get('inputfile')
    with open(inputfile) as fd:
        output = fd.read().replace('Hello', 'Goodbye')

    return output
```

Assuming that we have:

```
$ cat data
Hello world
```

We can call:

```
$ curl --unix-socket /tmp/app.sock   http:/cmd1 -d inputfile=$PWD/data
Goodbye world
```